Raspberry pi zero 2w serial communication error with sc16is740 on spi1
I have a raspberry pi zero with spi0 connected to w5500 and spi1 connected to sc16is740. The w5500 Interrupt pin is connected to GPIO25 and RsTn pin is connected to GPIO17 while the sc16is740 Interrupt Pin is connected to GPIO24.
The config.txt contents are updated to include the overlays as follows:
dtparam=spi=on

dtoverlay=spi1-1cs

dtoverlay=anyspi,spi0-0,dev="w5500",speed=30000000

dtoverlay=w5500

dtoverlay=sc16is752-spi1,int_pin=24,xtal=14745600

The eth0 port shows up and works fine, ttySC0 & ttySC1 ports also appear.
Since sc16is740 has 1 serial port, I use ttySC0 for the communication.
But when I test the data communication using python-serial, it is able to send data but on trying to receive data, errors occur. It would have garbage character post 8 characters.
On modbus communication, while behaving as a modbus master, its sends valid commands but is not able to read back the response and shows timeouts.
I am not able to understand what could be the possible reason.
Here is the schematic for reference:

